# Different Odd/Even Headers Affecting Page Numbers

Tags: headers

I'm using Word 2007

I am trying to have different headers for my odd and even pages

When I choose "Different Odd and Even Pages" under the Edit

Header menu, it eliminates my even footers. When I attempted to

manually insert the page numbers, it changed every other footer to

whatever the first number was I typed in.

I am very confused. Please Help!

Comment: Has my answer helped you? If so, you should upvote it and/or mark it as the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you set "Different Odd/Even" this will, indeed, remove all the information on the even pages. That's because, up to that point, all the headers and footers are "odd page".

This makes sense because usually the reason for choosing "Different Odd/Even" is because you want them to lay out differently.

That said, the way headers and footers work, you should only need to recreate one of the even page headers: the changes should then propagate to the other even pages. So you could COPY the content of an "even" page, activate the option, then paste into the new "even" page.

I don't understand, however, what you mean by "whatever number I typed in" in reference to page numbers. Since headers and footers repeat through out the document (unless you insert a section break and consciously "unlink" a new section from the previous one), anything you type in a specific type of header/footer automatically repeats (propagates). For dynamic information, such as page numbers, you need to insert a FIELD (Page field) that automatically generates the page number.

The tool for this is in Insert/Header & Footer/Page Number. You can choose "Top of Page" to put it in the Header; "Bottom of Page" to put it in the Footer, or Current postion if you're in the Header or Footer editing area.

For odd/even pages make sure your selection is on an odd / even page when you use the command.

If you have more than one section and have unlinked the header / footer from the previous section, then you need to use this command for each unlinked section if you want to see page numbers.

Comment: Let me make it clear that I 've inserted odds & evens headers and 
footers for different sections of a document. Now I want to insert page 
numbers in the headers or the footers. How should I do this?

Comment: edited my Answer...

Comment: Perhaps including some screenshots of how to achieve this might help?